# Javascript ILLEGAL char message when eval'ing text using new Function

Tags: javascript

We have a badge script that pulls a json config file and then loads external scripts asynchronously and executes code when they're loaded. The js is stored as a string in the JSON file. To avoid using eval() we're executing the code as follows:

```
var codeFromJSON = "alert('this far')";
var func = new Function(codeFromJSON);
func();
```

This works, but returns the following error in chrome, and similar errors in other browsers:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

At first I thought this had to do with something simple—copying the snippet from the web, etc.—but I've retyped and retested, and still get the same thing...

Any ideas?

Comment: um... that won't get you very far. `eval` is `eval`.

Comment: couldn't you use something like `require` or `$.getScript`?

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome...but that's irrelevant. This doesn't avoid the security issue of accidentally running malicious code from text. As for whether it creates a new instance of the js interpreter like `eval`, I'm not sure...

Comment: @nbrooks Javascript is never secure. You can always load in external scripts manually.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! The malicious code issue is sort of nullified now I think. Since JS consoles in all major browsers allow you to run any client-side code you want on any site. The key in this case was just to make sure that the snippet is walled in, so that it didn't conflict with other scripts that are running. And, I figured out the problem. Dumb mistake...